# How to remotely view activity logs from a Java EE app in Vaadin?

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, glassfish, vaadin

I'd like to remotely monitor the activity of my Java EE application (deployed on a glassfish server).
 Basically, I want my client-side implemented using Vaadin to display logs about the server-side activity.

The user would like to know what's happening on the server side...These logs should only be high-level informative messages

I guess it really depends on the logging framework used if any. I've seen Chainsaw for log4j but this is a client on its own.
Otherwise, I could remotely read a file line by line (like `tail -f`)...but I don't know how to do that either.

What's the best solution to achieve this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general what you could do is simply use a Vaadin Label, read a log file infinitely (or rather until stopped) and append the file content to the label. Here is code for a for that does exactly this:

```
      Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(LOGFILE));
                String line;
                while (running) {
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line == null) {
                        // wait until there is more lines in the file
                        Thread.sleep(POLL_MS);
                    } else {
                        // append to the log Label
                        synchronized (MyApplication.this) {
                            log.setValue(log.getValue() + line + "<br />");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: handle me
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO: handle me
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                running = false;
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignore) {
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    };
    t.start();
```

For this to work you need a ["RAW" mode Label](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.label.html) and a [ProgressIndicator](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.progressindicator.html) that polls the server:

```
    ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
    pi.setPollingInterval(POLL_MS);
    pi.setIndeterminate(true);
    layout.addComponent(pi);
```

Disclaimer: this code was from a non-critical application and for example error handling and HTML escaping is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to perform this functionality in your app.  I'm not sure you could leverage the pieces Chainsaw uses in Vaadin, but you can look at VFSLogFilePatternReceiver if you're curious.

Anyway, Chainsaw info if you want to try it out and see if it works for you:

Chainsaw can read log files, event remote ones available from one file systems supported by Commons VFS (http, ssh, ftp, smb).

If you'd like to, try out the latest developer snapshot - the configuration screen hopefully makes it clear how you can tail the log file, and has a ton of features not available in the currently-released version.

Snapshot available here:
http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy